# Change title on "More" tab

Tags: iphone, uitabbaritem, tabbarcontroller

Is there any way to change title on "More" tab (text on uitabbaritem)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well..If you want to change the title of the navigation bar of your more tab use the method given by 7KV7

and if you want to change the tab title ...

there is an another way..

suppose you have eight tabs..

1) In your tab Bar controller ...make only five tabs...remove all the other views other than five tabs..

2)lets make your fifth tab as your "more tab"...take it as a tableviewController and in it's tableView elements add elements as your sixth..seventh..eighth tab's name and image...

3)in fifthViewController's rowdidselect method navigate the sixth , seventh and eighth tab's respective view controllers..

Pros:-you can change the name and the image of the more tab
Cons:-well you can not use the edit button of your more tab where you can change the tab element's order..

try it if you are comfortable with this..

Comment: Thank you for idea, but it not suitable for me

Comment: @termit...what are you trying to do?? do you want to change the name of the more navigation bar only or do you want to change the title of more tab ?? because I have also used the mathod given by 7KV7 in a project...it worked great for me :)

Comment: I want to change the title of more tab

Comment: well then you can also add a label on the tabBar ..make the backgrounf black ...and font as other font... then put it just above more is written..it is possible :)...try it if you are comfertable

Answer (score 0):

Taken from this [Link](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=751625)

Yes, it is possible.

```
UINavigationBar *moreNavigationBar = tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar;
moreNavigationBar.topItem.title = @"Your title";
```

tabBarController is your UITabBarController

Answer (score 0):

In your UITabBarController you just add this simple line under the viewDidLoad and under superViewDidLoad:

```
 self.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Your Title";
```

So then it should look like this:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];   // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

     self.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Mer"; 
     }
```

To make it worked I also created a new Objective-c class naming it: "MyTabBarController". And then I clicked my TabBarController in storyboard and set the class to: "MyTabBarController". When I pasted the code in the .m file it worked perfectly.